# Process' mean, covariance and stationarity

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_t=Yt+Zt^2$ be random process, where $Y$,$Z$ are uncorrelated random variables, with characteristics: $EY=3$, $EZ=0.5$, $DY=1$, $DZ=0.05$. Find $X_t$ mean and covariance and prove whether process is wide-sense stationary.

Covariance:

$\Gamma(Y,Z)=E(YZ)-EYEZ=EYEZ-EYEZ=0$

How about its mean? Any hint?

Comment: Hint as requested: Linearity of expectation!  $E[aX+bY] = aE[X]+bE[Y]$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: So $EX_t=E(Yt+Zt^2)=tEY+t^2 EZ=3t+0.05t^2$, right?

Comment: Well, not quite. You have the idea down correctly, but $EZ=0.5$ in your problem statement while you used $EZ=0.05$ in the answer you worked out. One of these is a typographical error.

Comment: Thanks. Can I assume, that this process isn't wide-sense stationary -- ($EX_{t_1} \neq EX_{t_2}$)?

Comment: Yes, the fact that $EX_{t_1}\neq EX_{t_2}$ is sufficient to prove that the process is not stationary in the wide sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$

You've seen the answer to the first question in comments.  As for covariance, you're making it unreasonably complicated.
$$
\begin{align}
\cov(X_t,X_s) & = \cov(Yt+Zt^2,Ys+Zs^2) = \cov(Yt,Ys+Zs^2)+\cov(Zt^2,Ys+Zs^2) \\[8pt]
& =\cov(Yt,Ys)+\cov(Yt,Zs^2)+\cov(Zt^2,Ys)+\cov(Zt^2,Zs^2) \\[8pt]
& = st\cov(Y,Y) + ts^2\cov(Y,Z) + t^2 s\cov(Y,Z) + t^2 s^2 \cov (Z,Z) \\[8pt]
& = st\operatorname{var}(Y) + 0 + 0 + t^2s^2 \operatorname{var}(Z).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So the fact, that $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated, is useless?

Comment: @atomoutside : Why would you say that?  I used that fact above.  That's where the two $0$s came from.

Comment: Just noticed uncorrelation -- I first typed and later thought about $0$s. Am I on right path for proving non-wide-sense stationarity: ($EX_{t_1} \neq EX_{t_2}$) ?